# How can I boot a switching power supply driver/oscillator IC?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I am trying to design a simple switching power supply.  The idea is to produce a square wave using an NE555 then through MOSFET or BJT provide the pulse to switching step down transformer.  My problem is how to boot the NE555 or any other IC to do oscillation from mains after rectified since the voltage is too high for the IC.  If I use a simple resistor for that, the current is too high and the resistor will not be able to dissipate that powe.  After some research, I found that auxiliary coils are used for that purpose but still auxiliary coils require the IC to produce the oscillation first. What are some popular techniques to solve the booting problem?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but you are complicating things for yourself a lot by not using a dedicated PMIC.

Answer (score 2):

That's what so-called 'Bootstrap supplies' or 'Standby supplies' are for.

There are dedicated ICs that can provide, for example, 12V DC from 230V AC with only a few external components. Of course, it may not provide much power, but it's sufficient for bootstrapping your design.

Additionally, a 'helper power supply' can be implemented using a small transformer and rectifier. The components can be relatively small since not much power is required.

Furthermore, if you want to implement 'standby operation' for your power supply, there are dedicated ICs designed specifically for this purpose.

**EDIT:**

*I am trying to design a simple switching power supply* and *using NE555 then through MOSFET or BJT* contradicts itself.

There are dedicated ICs for such applications - and for very good reason.

Not only are all the loop stability, PWM setpoint, PWM control, feedback, power-loss optimization, and various other aspects already engineered and verified, but also far fewer components are typically required because of the extensive integration of components due to their widespread use. Additionally, there are application notes available that can significantly simplify the engineering process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , would you please provide the chip number of some ICs that are general purpose and provide this functionality  of low power supply form High voltage

Comment: @AbdAllahTalaat As i dont know your specific requirements: See www.digikey.com - they have it all and you can dow a parametric search.

Comment: @AbdAllahTalaat "shopping" (aka part recommendations) are specifically off-topic.